# Multi Select combo box in dojo grid

Tags: select, dojo, grid

I've implemeneted customised single select combo box as a cell element in dojo grid. Can someone tell me how to implement multi select conbo box?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get your highly specific question answered is to go through official channels, like [Dojox Grid Support](http://dojotoolkit.org/forum/532).

Comment: Link gives 404, I'd also argue it's not overly specific to be answered here.

Comment: Obviously I checked the link before publishing. It looks like in two years it was (re)moved. But thank you for your valuable feedback anyway.